# Restful resource naming for "secondary" tables

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, restful-url, api-design

Let's go with my example, I have 3 tables and I want to know what's the best method to name my resource url.

**Tables**:

1. building
2. building_type The most simple to define is #1.

**API resources**:

1. `GET someapi.com/buildings`
2. `GET someapi.com/**?**`

My problem is that I don't know what's the best practice for "secondary tables" like building_type.

**Maybe**:

- `GET someapi.com/buildings/types`
- `GET someapi.com/building-types`
- ...

I hope some of you will reach to enlighten me. Thanks.

Comment: do you really need to expose the list of building types? if you just need to display a building's type, exposing it through a `Type` property on the `Building` resource should be fine

Comment: This is why I need help. In my head, I have the need to expose all. Example, if I want to show on a page all the building types with their properties, I need to expose that resource, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to figure our the requirements for your API, the scenarios, use cases etc, and only then actually start building it.

To go back to your question, I'd go for `GET someapi.com/buildingTypes`, because `/buildings/types` will leave you with a "Types" resource which doesn't make much sense on it's own. You could indeed make it so it's only accessible once you go to the buildings resource, so `GET someapi.com/buildings/buildingTypes` could be the way to [navigate](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level3) to it.